# Boolean logic in SQL SELECT

Tags: sql, postgresql, boolean-expression

Is there a simpler way to implement

```
select (case when ((a is null) or (b is null)) then null else (case when
(a = b) then true else false end) end) from ...
```

in PostgreSQL, or other major RDBMS for that matter?

Comment: `select a = b` will return exactly the same thing or `a is not distinct from b`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think the simplest is:

```
select (a = b)
```

although this is not exactly your logic, because this returns `NULL` if either `a` or `b` are `NULL`.  It might be good enough.

If you want it to return `false` if *either* `a` or `b` are `NULL` but not both, then:

```
select (a = b) and nullif(coalesce(a, b) is null, true)
```

EDIT:

Because you ask about other databases, one way of expressing the logic would be:

```
(case when a = b then 1 when a <> b then 0 end) as flag
```

This returns `NULL` if either is `NULL`.

Comment: thanks. my logic is wrong. I want null if either is null (will changed the question).

Comment: @user66081 . . . That is the first option; it seemed like a reasonable interpretation.

Comment: For some reason I though it wouldn't work without trying. Do you know if this has a high chance of working on other major RDBMS?

Comment: @user66081 . . . If the database supports a boolean type then it should work.  Otherwise, you'll need more explicit logic.

Comment: `select a is not distinct from b` to get a null safe `a = b`

Answer (score 2):

You can write

```
SELECT CASE
       WHEN (a IS NULL) OR (b IS NULL) THEN NULL
       WHEN (a = b) THEN 'true'
       ELSE 'false'
       END
```

Comment: Did you copy the code from the OP's question and posted it as an answer?

Comment: No I was wrote answer when I was in bus so my network was weak and I send answer later and when I send it I see another answer